# How do I start Docker Desktop for Windows from command line?

Tags: command-line, docker-for-windows

I have set my [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) to not start up automatically at log in.

Is there a way to start Docker Desktop for Windows from the command line?

I can't find any reference to it in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/).

Answer (score 11):

#### Is there a way to start Docker Desktop for Windows from the command line?

> If you're using Docker for Windows, then simply start the desktop app
> installed in `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe`
>
> You can also stop Docker for Windows and run just the Docker daemon
> `dockerd.exe`. That'll only let you run Docker Windows Containers.
> `dockerd.exe` is in the program files directory.

Source [How do we start the daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182489/3536342), answer by [Shaun Luttin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108891/shaun-luttin)

Comment: It seems that the name of exe has been changed. I can find
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"

Comment: `dockerd` is currently in `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\dockerd.exe` after a default installation

Comment: Now sitting at `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\frontend\Docker Desktop.exe`. These jokers over at Docker will never stop with their shenanigans lol

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution in my node.js app

```
 async runDocker() {
const dockerExecutable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\Docker Desktop.exe';
const processName = 'Docker Desktop.exe';
const processes = await psList();
const dockerProcess = processes.find((process) => process.name === processName);

if (dockerProcess) {
  console.log('Docker Desktop is running.');
} else {
  console.log('Docker Desktop is not running.');
  exec(`start /MIN "" "${dockerExecutable}"`, { windowsHide: true }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing Docker Desktop: ${error.message}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Docker Desktop started successfully.');
  });
}
```

}