# Start Docker Desktop minimized on Win10 after login

Tags: windows-10, docker-for-windows

Is it possible to start Docker Desktop minimized after i log in on Windows?

---

I am aware that there is an option in the settings to enable the auto-startup

[image]

But when this is enabled, the full UI shows up after login

[image]

Also, running the `Docker Desktop.exe` from the [console](https://superuser.com/questions/1498570/how-do-i-start-docker-desktop-for-windows-from-command-line) or create a Shortcut with `minimized` as `Run` setting have the same unwanted behaviour.

---

Is there a way that only the whale icon shows up in the system tray and not the whole GUI?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Open the settings of the Docker Desktop, under `General` and uncheck `Open Docker Dashboard at startup`.

Comment: Warning with the latest version of Docker Desktop 4.27.1 (136059) the Open Docker Dashboard when Docker Desktop starts is ignored and the dashboard always shows on booting up my Windows 10 Pro laptop. Posting as an answer because I can't comment here yet.

Comment: @MikeWilliams - I got that issue too, hope they fix it soon as I don't want the Docker dashboard opening every time I login.

Comment: @MikeWilliams: I see the same issue with the version you've mentioned. It worked before with version 4.26.1 (131620). Even enabling it and disabling "Open Docker Dashboard when Docker Desktop starts" doesn't fix it. Appears to be a newly introduced bug in the latest release of Docker Desktop.